# Improve design of the website

Tags: feature-request, design

The design of this site is way too bland, I vote for better graphics and a better design.

Comment: You can add your ideas for better graphics/design [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/104/316), however they won't get implemented until after the site leaves beta

Comment: ::marches up and down Meta with a `BRING-BACK-SKETCHY` sign:: :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This site, as a beta site, uses the standard Stack Exchange Beta template. You can read more about the beta template in [The New Stack Exchange Beta Theme](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/), and probably other posts that others could point to quicker than I can.